# phpstorm project folder upload ignore path

Tags: phpstorm

I've got a project that has 2 different modules on git which are in two different folders on the server.

Example:

```
/webClient/this_is_the_root_of_web_client/
/serverSide/this_is_the_root_of_server_side/
```

I want to upload the client files to Apache root, but it still sent the `webClient` folder.
I tried to set the `webClient` folder as resource root, but still got the same result.

Comment: Marking folder as resources root does not affect Deployment in any way -- it's purely for CSS/HTML inspections inside the IDE. What you need to do is to set additional path mappings in Deployment settings (Path Mappings tab)

Comment: Can you give me an example? I just want the IDE to assume that I dont have the first folder. I can do a project in the root of that folder but I lose the git config.

Comment: Well: "Local path" to be set to full path to the desired local folder; "remote Path" -- "/" (root). NOTE: this should be your **additional** mapping (in case you already have one; you can have multiple mappings).

Answer (score 0):

Its SOLVED!

I configured 2 mappings:

```
   local                                  Server
--/localPath/projectFolder/webClient/  | /apachePath/

--/localPath/projectFolder/serverSide/ | /serverPath/
```

And it worked like a charm!

Thanks @LazyOne.